# PHP Rest API JIRA error 401 in version 2

Tags: php, jira

I am working with JIRA API's But when I called curl getting 401 error. Please let me where was my mistake.

The response is:

```
Unauthorized (401)

Encountered a "401 - Unauthorized" error while loading this page.
```

My Code is given below:

```
$username = '********@gmail.com';
$password = '********';

$url = 'https://vikasxtreem.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-9';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$issue_list = (curl_exec($curl));
echo $issue_list;
```

Comment: @Chilion No My username and password are corrent and working when login via https://vikasxtreem.atlassian.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to you construct and send basic auth headers yourself. To do this you need to perform the following steps:

- Build a string of the form username:password
- Base64 encode the string
- Supply an "Authorization" header with content "Basic " followed by the encoded string.

Make the request as follows:

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic ZnJlZDpmcmVk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://vikasxtreem.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-9"
```

And, as already mentioned, at the following to your call:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

Comment: username : password will be anything ?, I am using postman, how to build this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

to the list of options.

Also check whether you're going through a proxy which requires authentication too.